# How to make an array to store enum arrays in C?

Tags: arrays, enums

The scenario is like I am having 2 enum arrays:

```
FRUITS fruit1[2][3] = 
{
    {apple, kiwi, banana},
    {banana, kiwi, kiwi}
};

FRUITS fruit2[3][2] =
{
    {apple, banana},
    {apple, kiwi},
    {banana, kiwi}
};
```

How can I declare an array to store the above 2 arrays? Like:

TYPE Array[] = {fruit1, fruit2};

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't "store" them in this way because two your arrays have different dimensions. Dimensions are part of type and you're basically want to have array of elements with different types.

Another issue is that you cannot have two copies of your arrays without explicit `memcpy`.

If you want to have array of 2-dimensional arrays with different dimensions and work with them in run time, you should introduce for each array structures with pointer to first element in it and its dimensions. If course, you have to manage memory.

And this problem has nothing to do with `enum`s, I guess, because in C `enum` is just it's underlying type (`int`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. So  can you suggest me a way to store 2 same dimensional enum arrays?

Comment: If you want fancy way of accessing them, easiest way is to declare 3-dimension array. Or you may need array of pointers to your 2d arrays: `FRUITS *(Array[2][3])[] = {&fruit1, &fruit2}`. Or `FRUITS *(Array[3])[] = {fruit1, fruit2}` losing information of one dimension. But things are getting complicated here... You also can try to use `typedef FRUIT fruit_array2d_t[2][3]; fruit_array2d_t *Array[] = {&fruit`, &fruit2}`. Or make some struct that stores dimensions and simple linear chunk of memory and function that accesses elements.